# JavaScript regular expression replace - why does one work, but this other not?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I grabbed the following JavaScript regular expression replace from another site to strip out some invalid characters:

```
str = str.replace(/[^\u000D\u00B7\u0020-\u007E\u00A2-\u00A4]/g,'');
```

However, I noticed it wasn't catching occurrences of \00B7 (the ISO-8859-1 center dot character).

If I did it in two steps however, it works:

```
str = str.replace(/\u00B7/g,'');
str = str.replace(/[^\u000D\u00B7\u0020-\u007E\u00A2-\u00A4]/g,'');
```

The 1st replace seems to be included in the 2nd replace. Can somebody explain to me why the 2nd line doesn't work all by itself. Thanks.

Comment: I don't get it.  Do you want that character to be replaced or not?  If you do, just remove it from the negated character class: `/[^\u000D\u0020-\u007E\u00A2-\u00A4]/g`

Answer (score 2):

The first and second pattern are completely different. Pattern one replaces \u00B7, while the second pattern replaces all characters NOT listed in the pattern.  Remove the carat from pattern two and that should fix your issue.

Comment: If I remove the carat from pattern two what happens is that everything is removed except for a few control characters. All the good characters are also replace by ''. I admit I am confused. But that is what happens.

Comment: Because `\u0020-\u007E` represents a character range that is almost everything it the [ASCII character set](http://www.asciitable.com/), including all characters a-z, A-Z and numbers. So just remove `\u00B7` from the negated set and it will be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear:

```
/[^\u000D\u00B7\u0020-\u007E\u00A2-\u00A4]/
```

matches all characters **not** in the set. So to match \u00B7 (and have it replaced with ''), remove it from the pattern:

```
/[^\u000D\u0020-\u007E\u00A2-\u00A4]/
```

The ASCII character set is given at http://www.asciitable.com/, likely that is the set you want to keep. The range \u0020-\u007E covers most the common set that is of interest, the others are typically not wanted.

\u000D is a carriage return, I would investigate whether you really need u00A2, u00A3 and u00A4.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily want to throw out non-ASCII characters though, such as those in foreign languages such as Swahili or Thai. Not that there is much content in foreign languages, but still, since it's UTF-8.

Comment: The pattern in the OP will throw out all non–ASCII characters other than the three in the range \u00A2-\u00A4 (¢£¤), which is only 3. So you are already excluding pretty much all non–English characters.

Comment: Hmm.. What I'm really trying to do it just exclude characters which cause validation errors in XML 1.0.